# Calculate (If A=B, then "" else A) in Excel without evaluating A twice

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm intending to conduct a formula of the type:

```
 =IF(VOL("Site";"Date")=0;"";VOL("Site";"Date"))
```

where VOL is a function I'm using through an Add-In. The limitations of this Add-In is, among others, that it is prohibited to call two Add-In function inside a single formula. I.e. the code I've written above is invalid and will result in an error.

Is there a way of achieving the following:

```
=IF(LHS=RHS;"Value if True";LHS)   (2)
```

where LHS is Left hand side, RHS right hand side and the expression therefore checks if LHS is equal to RHS, and if so prints a corresponding value, else LHS, *without having Excel evaluate LHS twice*?

I haven't found any solution to this except importing the formula in one cell, and refer to that cell as the value to print if the logical expression in the IF statement is false, but this will become a quite extensive "double work". A solution like (2) would also become more readable, especially when LHS is of the type "'C:\pathtofile[filename]SheetName!'Cell".

Hope anyone has some clever solution to this

Comment: What values can `VOL()` return?

Comment: Positive decimal numbers ranging from 0 to some thousands

Comment: I don't quite see the connection between the first and the second IF formulas. Where does the Vol() function feature in your LHS/RHS scenario?  It seems totally unrelated. Surely you are not asking how to create an IF statement like `=if(A1=B1;formula;A1)` -- Or are you? It is not clear what your question is.

Comment: First: an instance of a particular IF formula which fails, and a description to why. Second: "A question if there is a way to achieve the following [general formula]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one (rather ugly) way, just using formulas:

```
=IFERROR(1/IFERROR(1/vol("Site";"Date"),0),"")
```

This makes use of the `IFERROR` function, which kind of does what you want but only tests for errors.  Division by zero results in an error, so the inner `IFERROR` returns zero if `VOL` is zero, and `1/VOL` otherwise.  Now we need to take the reciprocal again to return the original value, so we repeat the trick, this time returning `""` if there is an error.

If you want to test for another value (e.g. 3), just use something like:

```
=IFERROR(3+1/IFERROR(1/(vol("Site";"Date")-3),0),"")
```

A much neater way would be to create a function in VBA which wraps the `VOL` function and does what you want:

```
Public Function MyVol(varSite As Variant, varDate As Variant) As Variant
        MyVol = vol(varSite, varDate)
        If MyVol = 0 Then MyVol = ""
End Function
```

Assuming you can call `VOL` from VBA.

Comment: Thanks for providing both a regular formula and a VBA solution. This certainly helps!

Comment: Is this approach slow on large excel files (The VBA UDF)?